No Sound from Rodecaster Pro II to Denon DRA-800H with TS to RCA Cable
I'm having trouble getting sound from my speakers after connecting my Rodecaster Pro II to my Denon DRA-800H amplifier. I used a TS to RCA cable (1/4 inch TS to RCA), but no audio is coming through the speakers.
Here is the cable I bought (sorry for the french link) : https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B07G59NMWF?th=1
Also, here is the back of my Denon DRA-800H :

I plugged the cable to the AUDIO IN : 1 CBL/SAT (The third column from the upper left)
Then I plugged The cable to 1/L and 2/R (The speakers output from the Rodecaster) here is also a picture from the back of the Rodecaster Pro II :

I have also a headphone plugged in the output 1, and everything is working fine ; I have all the sounds I want.
In the RODE Central software, the routing configurations are exactly the same for the 2 outputs.
Also, I've unchecked the option that automatically mute the speakers when a microphone is plugged.
Do you know what did I do wrong ? Should I get a TRS to RCA cable and plug the cable to an headphone output instead ?
Thanks for your help !

Someone has downvoted the question. As a courtesy to both the OP and others, please write a comment on the reason for the downvote.

@ghellquist Thank you for that !

This is a strange one, it has pro AND consumer equipment. A RØDE "podcast studio" and a Denon home theatre device (I used a Denon 4ch mixer on stage for years which was a pro device which still works perfectly, so I know they do make semi-decent pro equipment, but this is not one). Home theatre is strictly off-topic, and unfortunately, the issue was with the Denon home theatre system, so I have to vote to close it.

It looks to me like you have the correct cable. Outputs from the Rode is nominally balanced (on a TRS connector) but in my experience most if not all equipment works correctly with a TS cable. The output level is a line level as the Denon accepts.
As there are a lot of settings both in the Rodecaster and in the Denon it seems to me that you have missed one somewhere. Difficult to say where. It will boil down to trying to test one thing at a time. One suggestions is to see if you have a phone or CD player or whatever that can output a line signal to check that the Denon takes input signal and plays back. Another suggestion is to to see if there actually is an output. You might start by testing "effects" outputs (the inbuilt sounds). Next step might be to see if the microphone output actually comes out of the Procaster. You migt try with a different amplifier, or even try with a headphone (it will not sound good).

Hello, thanks for your help !
I tried a lot of stuff before I understood that my Denon has 2 inputs named CBL/SAT : One DIGITAL, and one ANALOG.
Turns out I just had to switch the source named CBL/SAT to use the ANALOG source. Now everything works perfectly, I have sound !
Thanks for your help !
